# JSON code not valid

Tags: json, validation

I have this error in validate test of jsonlint.com:

```
Results

Parse error on line 1:
s: 39551: "a:35:{s:4
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

Can someboady help me to fix it?

Thank a lot in advance!

Comment: can you post full JSON ?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but perhaps the problem is that your JSON code is not valid.

Comment: @andruboy
I can't post full code, it's too long for stackoverflow post. :/

Comment: @SteYeu use http://pastie.org/ for pasting code

Comment: oopps sorry

http://pastie.org/9619962

@andruboy

Comment: is this your JSON code? please make sure about JSON check your JSON in this parser so you can get where is you missing http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: yes, it's that... many long...

I posted it, thank you again!

Comment: I hope you can see it, I need to post a link? :S

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: here: s:39551:"a:35:{s:4:"form";a:6:

Comment: @SteYeu, have You tried my solution with PHP unserialize() function?

Comment: @ValdasPetruliswww.beedo.net Hi, sorry for the delay in my response. No, I didn't, however there was an error in source code, so I didn't try to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

put those brackets on line one.

Comment: ...but I don't know where. :/

Answer (score 1):

You should provide code example. But it seems what is **not JSON, but serialized PHP**.
In that case You should use:

```
unserialize("a:35:{s:4  ...");
```

Instead of:

```
json_decode("a:35:{s:4  ...");
```